# How to add new item in to Combobox when program running in GTK#

Tags: c#, combobox, gtk

It's possible to create option in comboboxentry to add new item when program running?
i will to create combo box with value: "add new" and when user chose it he will se empty field in combo box and write here a new value?
It's possible or i need to use extra buttons and entry field?

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use the entry field of the combobox but you need to have an extra buttons to start procedure.
You should define the "Add new" as default statut to your CB

Comment: so when i have extra buttons to add or remove how to make clear field in combo box entry to add new data?

Comment: Use setEditable(true)

Comment: comboboxentry in gtk# dont have setEdtitable ;/